Установка модуля на пайтон
https://pypi.org/project/youtube_dl/
pip install youtube_dl --root-user-action=ignore

Установил модуль, но при выполнении кода
from pytube import YouTube

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xXk9QgqdbiE') #ссылка на видео.
print(yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4')) 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/z/data/www/dw.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pytube import YouTube
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'

Что необходимо выполнить, чтобы заработал установленный модуль?
Пробовал и так и так...
python /dw.py
python3.13 /dw.py


python3.13 -m pip list и ищите там модуль. Потому что pip install может ссылаться на системный питон, что скорее всего, а не на ваш

youtube-dl            2021.12.17 присутствует в списке

Но он не может найти другой ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytube'. причем тут youtube_dl если у вас в коде прямо используется совсем другой модуль from pytube import YouTube

@FoxFox про ffmpeg понятно.  А вот pytube нигде не используется в коде youtube_dl (гитхаб ничего не находит) и, как я понимаю, является альтернативной либой с похожим функционалом.

Python 3.13 - это вы рановато его использовать пытаетесь, он даже в релиз не вышел. На нем куча библиотек не будет работать.

Я только что ещё поборолся и таки добился скачивания 8k и любых других. С трудом, но таки разобрался и сделал технологию более-менее простой и вменяемой. Без ffmpeg.exe не работает в этой кухне ничего, но я и с этим разобрался. Модуль yt_dlp - пока не вижу лучшего варианта в этой сфере.

Ошибка в условии: pip install youtube_dl --root-user-action=ignore
Но при этом: from pytube import YouTube
Предлагаю использовать более современный и популярный модуль yt_dlp:
Установите современный Питон, сегодня это версия 3.12.6.
Обновите установщик: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip
Установите: pip install -U --compile yt_dlp
Скачайте в сети ffmpeg, извлеките из архива ffmpeg.exe.
Текст готового консольного скрипта для загрузки видео из YouTube (сохраните, например, как youtube.py в каталоге, поместите туда же ffmpeg.exe:
def youtube_download(v_url = "", v_quality = "", v_ffmpeg_folder = "", v_folder = "", v_quiet = False, v_noprogress = False):

 ok = True

 v_options = {
  "format": f"bestvideo[height<={v_quality}]+bestaudio/best",
  "ffmpeg_location": os.path.join(v_folder, "ffmpeg.exe"),
  "quiet": v_quiet,
  "noprogress": v_noprogress,
  "outtmpl": os.path.join(v_folder, "%(title)s.%(ext)s")
 }

 if ok and not v_url: print("Не указан веб-адрес видео!"); ok = False
 if ok and not v_quality: print("Не указано качество видео!"); ok = False
 if ok and not v_ffmpeg_folder: print("Не указан каталог, в котором находится ffmpeg.exe!"); ok = False
 if ok and not v_folder: print("Не указан каталог для сохранения видео!"); ok = False

 if ok:
  try: yt_dlp.YoutubeDL(v_options).download([v_url])
  except Exception as e: print(f"Ошибка выполнения загрузки видео! Подробнее:\n{e}"); ok = False

 return ok

#--Пример использования:
print("-" * 50 + "\nЗагрузка видео из YouTube:\n" + "-" * 50)

ok = True

import os
try: import yt_dlp
except Exception as e: print(f"Ошибка импорта модуля! Подробнее:\n{e}"); ok = False

if ok:
 v_url = "https://youtu.be/linlz7-Pnvw"
 v_quality = "1080" # 1080 - 1080p, 2160 - 4k, 4320 - 8k
 v_ffmpeg_folder = "." # каталог, в котором находится ffmpeg.exe
 v_folder = "." # каталог для сохранения видео
 v_quiet = False # отключение вывода в консоль
 v_noprogress = False  # отключение прогресс-бара

 ok = youtube_download(v_url, v_quality, v_ffmpeg_folder, v_folder, v_quiet, v_noprogress)

print("\nНажмите любую клавишу для продолжения...")
os.system("pause > nul" if os.name == "nt" else "read > /dev/null")


Проблему с No module named 'pytube' это естественно никак не решает

ТАК ПРОЧИТАЙТЕ КОММЕНТ! 5:1

Коммент, который тоже не по теме вопроса? Чего его читать, модераторы снесут как оффтопик да и всё

Мне это интересно. А вот 5:1 в пользу Танечки - очень даже по своему прикольная игра.

pytubefix Можно пожалуйста комментарий по модулю. То что при помощи него возможно скачивать видео, понятно. Но возможно ли скачивать в 4к,8к? Ни одного толкового приложения в нете не нашел.

Ни одного не нашли? Это бывает. Вот тогда: https://pytubefix.readthedocs.io/en/latest. Что касается качества, то там есть вот такая штучка: .get_highest_resolution(), которая сама найдёт самое лучшее качество из доступных и скачает именно его. Есть там и фильтрация доступных стримов, которая позволяет выкачивать какое-то избранное. Короче, там много чего есть. Я бы здесь выложил готовый скрипт, но из-за убого форматирования в комментах это вряд ли будет читаемо.

@FoxFox не вижу в нём упоминания возможности объединения видео и аудио стримов в один файл, то есть для нормального скачивания 4к,8к всё равно потребуется ffmpeg

Дайте мне адреса видео, где 4к и 8к, тогда и станет понятно что оно может, что нет.

Нет, не сможет качать 4к или не хочет. Скачал, но в самом низком разрешении. Не глюкнул. Ну, значит это не пойдёт. Лично меня и 1080 устроит. Это качает хорошо, без фокусов. Попробовал качать с помощью Wondershare UniConverter 16-минутный 4к. Скачалось. А 8к даже и в настройках нет.

То же и с 8к. Качают оба, но в более низком качестве.

Заменил ответ на другой. 4к, 8к  и прочее работает.

И опять весь ответ по существу находится в одной непонятной фразе «Но при этом» (но при этом что? Если автор сам не догадался в своём коде, значит и в вашем ответе тоже не догадается), а всё остальное опять не по теме вопроса

В комментариях УЖЕ написано. Роль попугая мне не очень интересна. Я пишу для многих, для тех, кто способен понимать код Питон.

«В комментариях УЖЕ написано» — ну а я уже неоднократно упоминал, что комментарии могут быть удалены модераторами в будущем. Поэтому некоторые участники зарабатывают репутацию путём копирования комментариев в ответы

Значит, автор спросит что ему непонятно. А если не спросит, значит ему не надо. Мне всё равно кто и чего тут удаляет. Я ответил и куда лучше, чем это обычно делают. И даже написал полностью готовое. Папочка уже всё сделал!

Давайте продолжим обсуждение в чате.
