Скачать видео в лучшем качестве через pytubefix
https://pytubefix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/captions.html
Установил, выполняю
from pytubefix import YouTube
from pytubefix.cli import on_progress

url = "url"
 
yt = YouTube(url, on_progress_callback = on_progress)
print(yt)

ys = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
ys.download()

Работает, но скачивает что та среднее по качеству. Каким образом возможно скачать видео в лучшем качестве, какое есть. Если видео 4к, скачать виедо в 4к. Если максимальное качество 480, скачать в 480..

Как минимум прочитать документацию функции get_highest_resolution https://pytubefix.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pytubefix.query.StreamQuery.get_highest_resolution

progressive = False Скачал без аудио, в разрешении 720. Это конечно лучше предыдущего, но скачиваемое видео доступно в разрешении 1080. К тому же, скаченный файл имеет 25fps, на ютубе тоже разрешение но 50fps

Ну тогда лучше попробуйте yt_dlp https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1594288

Могу предложить мой ответ в этой теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1594283/%d0%a3%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd/1594288?noredirect=1#comment2879211_1594288

Не прав был, работает. В прошлый раз, что то не так делал. Сразу скачать видео со звуком не выйдет как понимаю. Необходимо по отдельности одно и другое, а затем через ffmpeg объединить?

@flex да. . . .

mp3=True, скачиваем, в скаченном файле указан кодек AAC. Не шибко разбираюсь во всем этом. Разве ютуб, кодек не libopus использует.  Вроде да и он вроде лучше чем acc...

Только вчера убил на pytubefix и компанию подобных три часа. И всё равно пришлось отказаться. pytubefix - не связан напрямую с ffmpeg, код будет длиной три километра и крайне запутанный. Нативно вся эта кухня работает с yt_dlp.

Не понимаю, как по мне, вполне неплохо. Скачал видео, скачал аудио, объединил и готово. Что мне интересно, если имя файла на rus, ffmpeg не находит, приходиться переименовывать оба файла потом уже ffmpeg

Не имею проблем с кириллицей. Скачал с любым именем, ffmpeg собрал фрагменты в фоне, почистил аудио и видеостримы, без моего участия и  всё. Я ж говорил, будет много бестолкового кода в Вашем варианте, лишнего и глючного.

Ваша проблема №2 это вот это: .get_highest_resolution(). Вы предполагаете, что модуль действительно сам Вам выберет наилучшее качество? Нет, так будет очень даже не всегда. Попробуйте скачать 8к. Вы это уже видели сами. Попытки ручной параметризации в этом модуле лично у меня оказались бесплодными. yt_dlp имеет параметры, которые можно настраивать самому. Причём там выбор максимально возможного качества как раз работает. Если я укажу 2160, а имеется лишь 1080, то без вопросов скачает 1080.

P.S. Да и не всегда нужно качать наилучшее качество, даже если pytubefix работает. Вы представляете себе, что такое есть фильмец на полтора часа в качестве 8к? А оно там может быть в списке доступных.
